# Using round() function in c

Tags: c, rounding

I'm a bit confused about the `round()` function in C.

First of all, man says:

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <math.h>
   double round(double x);

RETURN VALUE
   These functions return the rounded integer value.
   If x is integral, +0, -0, NaN, or infinite, x itself is returned.
```

The return value is a `double` / `float` or an `int`?

In second place, I've created a function that first rounds, then casts to int. Latter on my code I use it as a mean to *compare doubles*

```
int tointn(double in,int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = (int)round(in*pow(10,n));
    return i;
}
```

This function apparently isn't stable throughout my tests. Is there redundancy here? Well... I'm not looking only for an answer, but a better understanding on the subject.

Comment: the return value is always a `double` or a `float`. If the number you input is something like `42.000` this is considered integral even though your passing a `double` or `float`. What do you mean by "isn't stable"?
If you're comparing `double`s you should also pay attention to the machine epsilon for floating point values.

Comment: You can see from the first part of the man that you post that the `round()`function returns a `double`.

Comment: you cannot rely on the precision of `pow(10,n)` when n is big. What's the usual/max value of `n` in your tests?

Comment: still not clear. if `42.000` is stored as a float or a double, it has a completely different meaning than `42.000` as an int.

Comment: you should use quote markup to include what man says. I was trying to edit it for you but got nearly done and the page refreshed as @MikeCAT corrected the images instead. Images are not a great way to include text.

Comment: As I said, I'm looking for but understanding the subject. Why does `man round` says _"these functions return the rounded integer value"_ in the return value field?
@Jean-FrançoisFabre, my usually max value is about 7.

Comment: *"This function apparently isn't stable"* Can you show some examples of this?

Comment: Makes sense: the rounded integer value as float/double: ex: `1.0`. your max value cannot be much bigger, the max value of the int is 2**31-1 if you're running 32 bits.

Comment: Input? Expected output? Actual output? BTW: `round` returns `double` - always - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html

Comment: `8.000` is the integer 8 expressed as a double. This is what the line means when it says it returns the integer value. It just does it with a double type. (integer != `int`)

Comment: Yes, it says "integer" not `int`. An integer is a whole number, not a language type.

Answer (score 6):

The wording in the man-page is meant to be read literally, that is in its mathematical sense. The wording "x is integral" means that *x* is an element of **Z**, not that *x* has the data type `int`.

Casting a `double` to `int` can be dangerous because the maximum arbitrary integral value a `double` can hold is 2^52 (assuming an IEEE 754 conforming binary64 ), the maximum value an `int` can hold might be smaller (it is mostly 32 bit on 32-bit architectures and *also* 32-bit on some 64-bit architectures).

If you need only powers of ten you can test it with this little program yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  int i;
  for(i = 0;i < 26;i++){
    printf("%d:\t%.2f\t%d\n",i, pow(10,i), (int)pow(10,i));
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Instead of casting you should use the functions that return a proper integral data type like e.g.: `lround(3)`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware about lround(). I will try it.

Answer (score 4):

here is an excerpt from the man page.

```
   #include <math.h>

   double round(double x);
   float roundf(float x);
   long double roundl(long double x);
```

notice: the returned value is NEVER a integer.  However, the fractional part of the returned value is set to 0.

notice: depending on exactly which function is called will determine the type of the returned value.

Here is an excerpt from the man page about which way the rounding will be done:

```
   These functions round x to the nearest integer, but round halfway cases
   away  from  zero  (regardless  of  the  current rounding direction, see
   fenv(3)), instead of to the nearest even integer like rint(3).

   For example, round(0.5) is 1.0, and round(-0.5) is -1.0.
```

Comment: "However, the fractional part of the returned value is set to 0."

In which precision that's true?

Comment: Nice that you've mentioned the "halfway cases". What about the fact that 0.5 could be either 0.5000001 or 0.49999998 for example? How does 'round()' deal with that?

Comment: @Mattana,  strongly suggest reading the man page for `round()` to get all the details/   ALL the part to the right of the decimal is set to 0 regardless of the 'precision' used in displaying the value.  That is one of the things that `round()` does.  a value with less than .5 will be rounded toward 0, like the `floor()` function.   a value with greater than .5 will be rounded toward infinity, like the `ceil()` function.  Besure to note the slight difference on the cases when the overall number is negative

Answer (score 1):

If you want a long integer to be returned then please use `lround`:

```
long int tolongint(double in)
{
    return lround(in));
}
```

For details please see [lround](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cmath/lround#:%7E:text=C%2B%2B%20lround%20%28%29%20The%20lround%20%28%29%20function%20in,argument%2C%20with%20halfway%20cases%20rounded%20away%20from%20zero.) which is available as of the C++ 11 standard.